# Easiest way to play sound from C/C++

Tags: c++, c, macos, audio

I have a function that generates `int` samples (say it's just a random function).

What's the easiest way I can route these ints to the speakers on my mac?

Note that it's important that I be able to just send ints indefinitely and it'd play it; I'm not looking for a way to write it to a WAV file and play it later or something.

Comment: Running `cout << '\a';` will play a sound if your PC has a typical PC speaker. This obviously isn't what you are asking though. Edit: I mean PC in the pure sense. Not the PC vs. Mac sense.

Comment: @Geoff_Montee: Yeah I need it for samples... not just a beep.

Comment: Yeah. It was a joke. I'm probably the only one that found it funny though. I think the standards for my sense of humor deteriorate as it gets later.

Comment: Have a look at this page, I think you can model your program on the example code that is there:  http://www.audiosynth.com/sinewavedemo.html

Answer (score 1):

I guess the simplest way is to go through [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/intro.en/usingsound.html) if you want something more crossplatform and less OSX specific. I personally used it to play raw samples and it worked like a charm.